# Azure VM Connection

Tags: azure, security, virtual-machine

I'm deploying my first VM in azure but I can only connect from Azure Joined devices, and I have some external users without company laptops that need to connect,

To increase the security, I'm deploying access control with MFA for this machine.

Thanks.

Comment: how are the users trying to connect? using RDP/ Bastion...what do you mean by enabling MFA

Comment: Sorry forgot to clarify, Using RDP, and MFA when accessing trough RDP.